# Unexpected C# bit shift right result

Tags: c#, bit-shift

I underestimated the complexity of the `>>` operator; it's not doing what I thought it would.

I want to right shift a `uint` value of 6542454. I thought it worked like this:

`val (is) == 11000111101010001110110`
`val >> 1 == 1100011110101000111011`
`val >> 2 == 110001111010100011101`
`val >> 3 == 11000111101010001110`
`val >> 4 == 1100011110101000111`
`val >> 5 == 110001111010100011`
`val >> 6 == 11000111101010001`
`val >> 7 == 1100011110101000`

In reality, the results are:

`val >> 1 == 1100011110101000111011`
`val >> 2 == 110001111010100011101`
`val >> 3 == 11111001100100110010011`
`val >> 4 == 1111100110010011001001`
`val >> 5 == 111110011001001100100`
`val >> 6 == 11111001100100110010`
`val >> 7 == 10011011111110111111100`

The 3rd operation clearly does something I don't understand and things go off the rails from there. Seems to do the thing I don't understand again at the 7th operation as well.

Using the `>>=` operator 7 times in a row yields values I would expect:

`val >>= 1 == 1100011110101000111011`
`val >>= 1 == 110001111010100011101`
`val >>= 1 == 11000111101010001110`
`val >>= 1 == 1100011110101000111`
`val >>= 1 == 110001111010100011`
`val >>= 1 == 11000111101010001`
`val >>= 1 == 1100011110101000`

Why does `val >> 3` not yield the same result as 3 calls to `val >>= 1`?

UPDATE:

My fault for [using a decimal to binary converter on the web that was truncating my decimal input to 7 digits](http://acc6.its.brooklyn.cuny.edu/~gurwitz/core5/nav2tool.html). When copy + pasting decimal values from Visual Studio, I didn't notice the truncation occurring.

The actual value being shifted is 6542454**26** and as everyone is correctly pointing out, C# is bit-shifting this value perfectly.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example program that replicates the problem?  The behavior you've described violates the C# specification, so it's worth checking if you have a different problem, such as operator precedence issues in your code that computes the shift.

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using to print out the values? You >>3 shows almost correct  result in Dec (8178067) instead of 817806. So I guess your printing code is off...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote code to output each shift:

```
uint i = 6542454;

for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
{
    uint k = i >> j;
    Console.WriteLine("{1} = {0}", Convert.ToString(k, 2), k);
}
```

and this is what I would expect to and did see.

```
6542454 = 11000111101010001110110
3271227 = 1100011110101000111011
1635613 = 110001111010100011101
817806 = 11000111101010001110
408903 = 1100011110101000111
204451 = 110001111010100011
102225 = 11000111101010001
51112 = 1100011110101000
```

Comment: Yes, I just did the same and I am too getting expected results.